# Combine the latest values of a nested Observable on demand

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have some custom fields that each have a value that can be retrieved using a `BehaviorSubject<Value>`. What fields are shown are based on what I get from the API, so in the end I have n amount of `BehaviorSubject<Value>`s. I would like to group these values together into an `Observable<List<Value>>` where the list contains latest values from these fields (order is irrelevant). The problem however is that these fields are not all available at the same time because they're created while the UI loads so I cannot use `Observable.combineLatest` with the list of subjects.

What I currently have done is I have created the following variable:

```kotlin
private val values = BehaviorSubject.create<Pair<Int, Value>>()
```

I use this subject to subscribe to all of the field's subjects but map the subjects first with their position and make a pair of it.

```kotlin
fieldSubject.map {
    Pair(position, value)
}.subscribe(values)
```

What I then want to do is group the values based on their position in the pair and get an `Observable<List<Value>>` where the list contains the latest values from each position. However I don't know how to proceed after grouping them using `groupBy`:

```kotlin
values.groupBy {
    it.first
}
```

This results in an `Observable<GroupedObservable<Pair, Value>>>`. Finally this is how I think I should get to `Observable<List<Value>>`, but I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupBy` doesn't seem helpful to me here.

Accumulating values is generally done using `scan`, here you can use a transformation like:

```
values.scanWith({ arrayOfNulls<Value>(N) }) { acc, (index, value) ->
    acc.copyOf().apply {
        set(index, value)
    }
}
    .map { it.filterNotNull() }
```

You could probably get away without `copyOf()`, but I think I encountered problems in the past when the accumulator function wasn't pure.

By the way, you can write `position to value` instead of `Pair(position, value)`.

Also, you can use `merge` to get an `Observable<Pair<Int, Value>>` instead of creating a `BehaviorSubject` and subscribing it manually to all fields:

```
Observable.mergeArray(
    fieldX.map { 0 to it },
    fieldY.map { 1 to it },
    fieldZ.map { 2 to it }
    // ...
)
```

So overall, you could have a function that does it all for you:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> accumulateLatest(vararg sources: Observable<out T>): Observable<List<T>> {
    return Observable.merge(sources.mapIndexed { index, observable ->
        observable.map { index to it }
    })
        .scanWith({ arrayOfNulls<T>(sources.size) }) { acc, (index, value) ->
            acc.copyOf().apply {
                set(index, value)
            }
        }
        .map { it.filterNotNull() }
}
```

And then just call:

```
accumulateLatest(fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ)
    .subscribe {
        println("Latest list: $it")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about the scan function in ReactiveX. I understand why you want to keep it pure and thanks for the Pair tip!

Comment: No problem! I've updated the answer because the whole functionality can be encapsulated in a function (if that fits your purpose).